# Given a string that is a range of excel cells 'A1:F1' how would one go about interpolating this range in PHP?

Tags: php, regex, excel

I would like to fill this 'A1:F1' out to either an array or a string such that it now equals array {A1, B1, C1, D1, E1, F1} or "A1:B1:C1:D1:E1:F1"

Does anyone have an efficient idea on how to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen sorry about that. I edited my question title now.

Comment: `preg_replace_callback` could be used for what you are trying to achieve. Showing what you've tried would improve the question. Here's a starting point, `preg_replace_callback('~([A-Za-z])(\d+):([A-Za-z])\d+~', function($match) {`.. I also don't know much about excel so that might be allow invalid sequences.

Comment: Thanks for your advice @user3783243  I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one possible solution. It works in two dimensions. As can be seen in the output, it works column by row, to reverse that simply requires changing the order of the two `for` loops.

```
function split_range($range) {
    list($start_cell, $end_cell) = explode(':', $range);
    if (!preg_match('/^([A-Z]+)(\d+)$/', $start_cell, $start) || !preg_match('/^([A-Z]+)(\d+)$/', $end_cell, $end)) return array();
    $cells = array();
    for ($c = $start[1]; str_pad($c, strlen($end[1]), " ", STR_PAD_LEFT) <= $end[1]; $c++) {
        for ($r = $start[2]; $r <= $end[2]; $r++) {
            $cells[] = "$c$r";
        }

    }
    return $cells;
}

echo implode(':', split_range("A1:F1")) . "\n";
echo implode(':', split_range("A1:A6")) . "\n";
echo implode(':', split_range("B2:D4")) . "\n";
echo implode(':', split_range("Q3:AB4")) . "\n";
```

Output:

```
A1:B1:C1:D1:E1:F1
A1:A2:A3:A4:A5:A6
B2:B3:B4:C2:C3:C4:D2:D3:D4
Q3:Q4:R3:R4:S3:S4:T3:T4:U3:U4:V3:V4:W3:W4:X3:X4:Y3:Y4:Z3:Z4:AA3:AA4:AB3:AB4
```

Answer (score 0):

**If I don't misunderstood your question**, then is one solution to achieve what you said on your question using php. But let me know if I am on wrong track :)

```
<?php
$str = 'A1:F1';
$arr = explode(":",$str);
$start = $arr[0];
$end = $arr[1];
$range = range($start[0],$end[0]);
$func = function($value) use ($start){
    return $value.$start[1];
};
$result  = array_map($func,$range);
echo "{".implode(',',$result)."}";
echo PHP_EOL;
echo implode(':',$result);
?>
```

**Output:**

```
{A1,B1,C1,D1,E1,F1} 
A1:B1:C1:D1:E1:F1
```

**DEMO:** https://3v4l.org/iDsGe